# How to pass a pandas DataFrame to a PostgreSQL Function (Stored Procedure)?

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, stored-procedures

Any ideas on getting data into a PostgreSQL stored proc / function from Python?

I have a DataFrame built up from other data sources and I need to do some work with Postgres and then INSERT/UPDATE some data in PostgreSQL if the query is successful. I know I can get it to work using just Python and raw SQL queries in Python strings and inserting variables where needed, but I know this is poor practice.

In the past I've been able to pass a C# DataTable from C# to a SQL Stored Procedure using MS SQL Server and User-Defined Table types. Is there a way to do something similar with Python DataFrames within PostgreSQL?

[This link](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/call-stored-procedures/) has been really helpful on the syntax for Python variables to Postgres function, but I have not seen anything on passing Pandas DataFrames to a PostgreSQL function. Is this possible? Is there a different design pattern I should be using?

Comment: how will your postgres function handle dataframe?

Comment: I am not following how function will make sense out of python dataframe. There are ways inserting/updating data from pandas using to_sql which will allow you to insert and update data in your postgres db. If thats not what you want then you might have to elaborate on your specific requirement.

Comment: @mad_ - You can pass a C# DataTable to MS SQL Server stored_procedure. I think the solution you're getting at is creating / updating a table in Postgres from data_frame.to_sql(), and then utilizing the table that you just created in the Postgres function. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Well C# datatable and MS Sql might have special bonding as they live under one roof. On the other hand, pandas and Postgres do not. What I was suggesting is to use to_sql to insert the data from your dataframe to your table. I cannot see any other option.

Comment: Okay! That seems like a good idea and possibly the only work around. However, in C#/MS SQL it was using a 'user defined table type', so not special bonding. I created this myself. So I was wondering if (1) Postgres supports anything like 'user-defined table types' and (2) if Python supports passing complex objects to Postgres.

Comment: ohh if you are looking something user defined then Sqlalchemy might be a good option for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code in PostgreSQL Function unsing python to retrive data from table, manipulate them and return them. The proper way to do it is to use the build in connector of the extension plpy which is a local connection runtime.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.plpy_func_simple(
    )
    RETURNS TABLE(key numeric, value numeric) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpython3u'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
  import pandas as pd
  
  data_lt = plpy.execute('SELECT "key", "value" FROM public."<your-table>" ORDER BY "key"'); #PLyResult --> List or Dictionary
  data_df_x = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_lt)['key'];
  data_df_y = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_lt)['value'];
  df = pd.concat([data_df_x, data_df_y], axis=1).values
  
  return df;
$BODY$;
```